# What reference do I need to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, visual-studio-express

I am interested in using C# to manipulate/Automate Excel files.

After browsing the web I have found [VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430) but it seems you can not use that in Visual Studio Express Edition so I can not use that.

Just few minutes ago I noticed a question in this site that used this namespace in its code:

**Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel**

So I am wondering if all I need to use that is add necessary reference and if so which reference to add?

**UPDATE**

I installed "Primary Interop Assemblies" as the accepted answer suggested but for some reason they are still missing in the Add Reference dialog under ".NET" but they are present in GAC.

So I just added the reference using "Browse" and located `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` in GAC folder.

But looking for similar questions on this site regarding adding reference from GAC it seems this is not recommended.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

## Update (thanks user2347528)

These assemblies are available as NuGet packages, which is much easier than my original answer.

You can install by either right clicking on **References** in your project and selecting **Manage NuGet packages...** and searching for one of the packages listed below, or install using the Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

- [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel)
- [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word)
- [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook)
- [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint)
- [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph)

---

These are available as "Primary Interop Assemblies", which can be installed with Office, or downloaded and installed separately. [How to: Install Office Primary Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Once those are installed, you can reference them in your project in the Add Reference dialog, under .NET. If you do not see those Microsoft.Office.Interop assemblies listed, then they have not been installed yet. Install them from your setup, or download and install them separately (see my link above for the downloads).

Comment: I found bunch of components in "Com" tab named Microsoft Office....  Are those it?

Comment: Those are COM services that Visual Studio can generate .NET interop assemblies for. It is not recommended that you use those; you should use the PIA assemblies released from Microsoft. They should show up in the .NET tab in the Add References dialog. If you do not see them, you need to install the PIA from your Office setup or download them separately as I linked in my answer.

Comment: @HackedByChinese  I don't see any .NET tab in the add References dialog

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013, I found these references under Assemblies->Extensions in the left menu of the Add References window.

Comment: I'm trying to install a C# program that uses the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll on a Windows 2012 server. The program works fine on my Windows 7 PC, but even after installing the PIA's on the server, I still get an error message about System.Runtime.Interop.COM components missing. The program breaks when I try to instantiate the Excel.Application() object. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: @Melanie Of course, just to be sure, you'll have to have Office installed on the server. Other than that, this is a new(er) feature in VS that could help you with deployment: Embedding interop types. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/32bf2a52-bffa-4cc8-a635-c75f36b623e9/cant-install-microsoftofficeinteropexceldll-on-windows-server-2012-r2?forum=exceldev

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, Embed Interop Types is set to true on the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference in my project, so that's not the answer either. Grumble. At this point, I'm just going to run the darn thing off my PC.

Comment: Visual Studio Nuget has this package. Its one step to add it from Nuget.

Answer (score 50):

Just had this problem myself and accepted answer didn't help me but I solved it with:

`Add reference > Browse > C: > Windows > assembly > GAC > Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel > 12.0.0.0_etc > Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`

Comment: I was looking for this solution everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's deliciously ironic that Microsoft themselves cannot get this working reliably - 2014 and we are still referring directly to .dlls ...

Comment: `Add Reference` -> `COM` -> `Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library` does the same.

Comment: Is it working on server? without installing office on server?

Comment: ok thanks. do you have any idea? can i use it without installing office.. I am using azure.

Answer (score 25):

Answers didn't help me to solve my problem, I couldn't find (and browse) the assemblies although I installed them using Microsoft's msi installer. For me, the excel assembly is located under `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`

Comment: After i tried the Folder GAC, GAC_32 and GAC_64 i thought it will never be in the last folder GAC_MSIL.  But it was. Thanks for your comment. Worked great for me!

Comment: Simplest and best answer. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 8):

Just add reference of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.

It includes MicroSoft Excel related classes, no need to add more references.

Comment: That is the first thing I tried. But "Office" part is not found.

Comment: Actually had the same problem as @user850010 but finally realized I was right-clicking and adding on the references folder of the wrong project in my solution.

Answer (score 4):

I guess what you are trying to do is add `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` with `using` statement with out adding its reference in your application, in that case it wont be found. Before calling it with `using` statement you need to add a reference to ur application. Right click on `References` and add the `Excel Interop` reference.

Answer (score 4):

Add reference > Browse > C: > Windows > assembly > GAC > Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel > 12.0.0.0_wasd.. > Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll

Answer (score 4):

I found it located under Assemblies->Extensions in VS2013.

[image: Add Reference]

Answer (score 3):

If you have Microsoft Office installed, then you should be able to add a reference to Interop.Excel.

For example, the PC I'm typing this on has MSVS 2010 C# Express and Office 2010.  I can add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 11.0.0.0.

'Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

its in the com component, named:
"Microsoft Office 14 Object Library"

Comment: VS2010: Adding a COM reference to "Microsoft Office 14 Object Library" only adds a reference to "Microsoft.Office.Core". Better: Use the COM reference "Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library". It points directly to the installed Excel executable, but will show up as a reference to both "Microsoft.Office.Core" and "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel". Should help if you only need to run and deploy on machines which have Excel installed.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem, but none of these answers helped me.  I did find the dll on my pc in the location Mostey noted: (`C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`), but this is not the one that was referenced in the project I was trying to get building.

The reference in our project in Visual Studio 2012 was pointing to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\`.  This location was empty for me, but it worked fine for everyone else.  It took a number of tries, but I finally tracked down a working installer.  I hope this saves others the same hassle!

**-->  [Office Tools Bundle installer for VS2012](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/F/6/2F6A4FFA-D409-40C8-AF68-F6F0CBE0A00D/ENU/officetools_bundle.exe) <--**

This was located on the [Office Documentation and Download](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/aa905340) page.  Scroll down to **Tools Downloads**.  There's also currently one for VS2013.

Answer (score 3):

The best option since office 2007 is using [Open XML SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) for it.
We used Word.Interop but it halt sometimes, and it is not recommend for Microsoft, to use it as a server side document formatting, so Open XML SDK lets you creates word documents on DOCX and Open XML formats very easily.
It lets you going well with scability, confidence ( the files, if it is corrupted can be rebuild ), and another very fine characteristics.

Answer (score 2):

Here is super solid solution, you just need have excell.dll in your Debug/Release folder
Mine is 77,824 bytes, I downloaded it as a file, this also explain why some people have Debug compiled but Release not or vice versa.

Trento

Answer (score 1):

1.Download and install: Microsoft Office Developer Tools

2.Add references from:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the Microsoft.Office.Interop was not appearing in "Add Reference" option once I upgraded VS2012 to VS2015. I basically repaired the installation (*Control Panel > Programs & Features > VS 2012 > Right click Change > Repair*) and added the Microsoft Office component. After that the same solution started working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project is 32 bit.

I had this problem, as soon as I ticked "Prefer 32 bit and rebuilt" all the Office Interop assemblies where available in Reference->Assemblies->Search "Office".