# Can't add a reference to microsoft.office.interop.excel

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, reference, excel-interop

I am running Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4.5, and Office 2010.  I get a warning on some legacy code that I am trying to run that I am missing an assembly reference for  `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel==12.0.0.0` and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access==12.0.0.0`.

After searching, I was able to find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477977/what-reference-do-i-need-to-use-microsoft-office-interop-excel-in-net)

I installed the [Primary Interop Assemblies](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508), they show up in my control panel when I go to Add/remove programs.  However, I still do not have a selectable reference to the interop assemblies from the add reference dropdown for COM or .NET addins in Visual Studio.  I also do not have the interop assemblies when I navigate to `C: > Windows > assembly > GAC`, as was suggested in the previous post.

Searching my system for anything labeled '.Interop' does not yield the Office.Interop files.  Really frustrating, because it says that the assemblies are installed.

Adding a simple reference to Microsoft.Excel and Microsoft.Access COM addins does not remove the warnings.

**UPDATE:**  I was able to get this working.  Version 12.0 of the Interop Assemblies is native to Office 2007.  I was running Office 2010 which has version 14.0 of the assemblies.  The assemblies are backwards compatible, but I was unable to 'see' them in the browser because I had to select my project to build on 'Any CPU' instead of just 'x86'.

Comment: Is your target framework correct in your project properties?

Comment: the GAC is C: > Windows > Microsoft.NET > assembly

Comment: @Sam Yes, targeted for .NET 4.0

Comment: @terrybozzio Don't see Microsoft.Office.Interop anything in any of the folder in that path

Comment: Yes, you have to "Browse" for the Project.  Also, you have to know where they are ... Not too hard, but also not at all obvious.  You could also add your solution above as an answer to your question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get this working. Version 12.0 of the Interop Assemblies is native to Office 2007. I was running Office 2010 which has version 14.0 of the assemblies. The assemblies are backwards compatible, but I was unable to 'see' them in the browser because I had to select my project to build on 'Any CPU' instead of just 'x86'.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select 'Microsoft Office Developers Tools' when installing visual studio.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54ds2za4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Btw, if you get 'A selected drive is no longer valid' message when changing vs setup, uninstall sp1 first.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen when going back to a very old version of Office (went from 360 to 2000)... I had to download the PIA redistributables from here:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508

Then I had extract the .msi file that the "PIARedist.exe" file created. I used 7-zip for that. (Running the .msi installer didn't work for some reason.  Not quite sure why...)  I removed the reference to "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel", and then I added/browsed for "EXCELPIA.DLL" which I had extracted from the .msi file.  This seemed to resolve the issue I had.