# using interop assemblies for excel in c# application

Tags: c#, .net, excel-interop

I was wondering about the following Scenario:
I developed a C# application, that generates Excel reports based on the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Assemblies and installed the application on a Windows 2003 Server without installed Excel, but I don't get it to work there.

So basicly: Do I Need Office on the machine, where I want to use the above named assemblies or might it be for other reasons?

Thanks in advance for all well meant answers.

Comment: You will need to have a copy of excel on the server. I had to do a web application a few months ago with word and this was one of the reasons why I didn't use interop but open office sdk

Comment: Have a look here, very similar to what you try to achieve

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477977/what-reference-do-i-need-to-use-microsoft-office-interop-excel-in-net

Comment: Use a library like EPPlus that works on top of Office XML SDK to create the file. By definition the Interop assemblies require Excel on the server - they exist to make calling Excel easier, so you don't have to build them from scratch by adding a COM component reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to have Excel installed on your server.  Also, there are special licensing requirements for this, so please see:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757