# adding Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference

Tags: c#, .net, vba, excel

I am attempting to write a c# script that performs work on an excel spreadsheet. (Rather then a VBA macro).  I am trying to add the reference to the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` assembly.  I cannot find any reference to said assembly in the Add Reference... Window or by browsing to `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC`.  It does not exist.  I uninstalled and reinstalled office, and I also downloaded and installed the PIA redistributable located [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508).  The Microsoft.Office.Core is the closest assembly I found, added via COM -> Microsoft Office 14 / 15 Object Library. Any comments or advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a copy under C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL. Is it there for you?

If that doesn't work, open Windows Command Processor and use

```
dir /s microsoft.office.interop.excel.*
```

Answer (score 1):

In my `C#` project, the path is

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll
```

I am using `Excel 2010`

You might want to have a look at a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477977/what-reference-do-i-need-to-use-microsoft-office-interop-excel-in-net).

Comment: this works.  I did see that post, now I see several of the answers BELOW the ones I was attempting were correct. I was following `Add reference > Browse > C: > Windows > assembly > GAC > Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel > 12.0.0.0_etc > Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`