# Excel 2007 is installed in the system but not able to detect it by code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel

Excel 2007 is installed in the system but not able to detect it by code.

Here is my code

```
Excel.Application _excelApp = null;
_excelApp = new Excel.Application();
```

_excelApp  is returning null value.

Comment: There are lots of issues doing this from ASP.Net and its not recommended by Microsoft.  A constructor can't return null so something else is occurring, No exception is thrown at all?

Comment: That is absolutely impossible...

Comment: Do you want to uninstall Excel 2007 programatically?

Comment: It turns out that in this case constructor can create null object. Read this article [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: But this is happening, not able to find exact issue. @AlexK.

Comment: I don't want to uninstall the excel. This is working fine in one system, but not in other system.@MicrosoftDN

Comment: Exactly the same Excel on both systems? 2007 vs 2010, 64 bit vs 32 bit

Comment: Is it really matter 64 bit or 32 bit?@sq33G

Comment: @Deepakgupta check this SO thread: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477977/what-reference-do-i-need-to-use-microsoft-office-interop-excel-in-net) it says about installing office interop assemblies. Also check assembly references mentioned there.

Comment: Which version of [Microsoft PIA](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18346) are you using with your project?