# Library for work with Word Document of format *.doc.

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, doc

Can anybody get some link to library for work with Word Document of format *.doc.
I need the library which not require that Word or any other Office dependencies be installed on the server machine. 
I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word library, but it fail on service.

Comment: This previously asked question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477977/what-reference-do-i-need-to-use-microsoft-office-interop-excel-in-net

Answer (score 0):

Try Aspose Words for .Net http://www.aspose.com it is not free, but it works well.